# Camel smpp consumer inflight exchanges keep growing

Tags: apache-camel, smpp, jsmpp

I configured a route that listens to incoming SMS. 
The route receives a lot of sms and everything seems to go fine except for 2 things:

1. The number of inflight exchange grow slowly but constantly (after an uptime of 55 hours I have 250 inflight exchanges.
2. The number of inflight exhange seems to be linked to error below:

I'm using **camel 2.10.0**.

This obviously is not normal, I would like to know if somebody has been experiencing the same problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
>  2012-10-08 12:11:51,039 WARN [pool-27-thread-3]
> o.a.c.c.s.SmppConsumer [CamelLogger.java:224] Caused by:
> [java.lang.NullPointerException - null] 
> java.lang.NullPointerException: null 
>         at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:515) ~[na:1.6.0_31] 
>         at org.apache.camel.component.smpp.SmppMessage.createBody(SmppMessage.java:81)
> ~[camel-smpp-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0] 
>         at org.apache.camel.impl.MessageSupport.getBody(MessageSupport.java:41)
> ~[camel-core-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0] 
>         at org.apache.camel.impl.MessageSupport.copyFrom(MessageSupport.java:135)
> ~[camel-core-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0] 
>         at org.apache.camel.impl.MessageSupport.copy(MessageSupport.java:124)
> ~[camel-core-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0] 
>         at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultUnitOfWork.<init>(DefaultUnitOfWork.java:91)
> ~[camel-core-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0] 
>         at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultUnitOfWork.<init>(DefaultUnitOfWork.java:71)
> ~[camel-core-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0] 
>         at org.apache.camel.processor.UnitOfWorkProcessor.createUnitOfWork(UnitOfWorkProcessor.java:190)
> ~[camel-core-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0] 
>         at org.apache.camel.processor.UnitOfWorkProcessor.process(UnitOfWorkProcessor.java:102)
> ~[camel-core-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0] 
>         at org.apache.camel.processor.RouteInflightRepositoryProcessor.processNext(RouteInflightRepositoryProcessor.java:48)
> ~[camel-core-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0] 
>         at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)
> ~[camel-core-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0] 
>         at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)
> ~[camel-core-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0] 
>         at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99)
> ~[camel-core-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0] 
>         at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)
> ~[camel-core-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0] 
>         at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:73)
> ~[camel-core-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0] 
>         at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:99)
> ~[camel-core-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0] 
>         at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:86)
> ~[camel-core-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0] 
>         at org.apache.camel.component.smpp.MessageReceiverListenerImpl.onAcceptDeliverSm(MessageReceiverListenerImpl.java:71)
> ~[camel-smpp-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0] 
>         at org.jsmpp.session.SMPPSession.fireAcceptDeliverSm(SMPPSession.java:445)
> [org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jsmpp-2.1.0_4.jar:na] 
>         at org.jsmpp.session.SMPPSession.access$0(SMPPSession.java:443)
> [org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jsmpp-2.1.0_4.jar:na] 
>         at org.jsmpp.session.SMPPSession$ResponseHandlerImpl.processDeliverSm(SMPPSession.java:462)
> [org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jsmpp-2.1.0_4.jar:na] 
>         at org.jsmpp.session.state.SMPPSessionBoundRX.processDeliverSm0(SMPPSessionBoundRX.java:109)
> [org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jsmpp-2.1.0_4.jar:na] 
>         at org.jsmpp.session.state.SMPPSessionBoundRX.processDeliverSm(SMPPSessionBoundRX.java:51)
> [org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jsmpp-2.1.0_4.jar:na] 
>         at org.jsmpp.session.PDUProcessTask.run(PDUProcessTask.java:81)
> [org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jsmpp-2.1.0_4.jar:na] 
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
> [na:1.6.0_31] 
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
> [na:1.6.0_31] 
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [na:1.6.0_31]
```

Answer (score 2):

That's how fast and responsive the camel team is:

bug created and fixed
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-5693

Thanks Claus.